# SDL on iOS main function

Tags: ios, c, xcode, sdl

I have an XCode project linking to SDL3.framework indicated by these steps: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL3/README/ios

Now in main.c I have:

```c
#include <SDL3/SDL.h>
#include <SDL3/SDL_main.h>

#include <renderer_run.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  run_main_renderer();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the XCode project, I get the following error:

```
Entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64
```

I have yet to find a solution to this issue.

(I am trying to run the app on the iPhone simulator)